# Loading image problem in libGDX

Tags: java, libgdx

So i recently started learning libGDX, and I'm running into an error which did not occur in the tutorial series I was following.

I'm loading the image using :

```
killSkull = new Texture("KillSkull.png");
```

I made sure that i got the name as well as the extension correct, and the image is there in the assets folder.

I still get the error :

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't load file: KillSkull.png
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap.<init>(Pixmap.java:149)
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.TextureData$Factory.loadFromFile(TextureData.java:98)
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.<init>(Texture.java:100)
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.<init>(Texture.java:92)
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.<init>(Texture.java:88)
at com.saumi.game.assets.Assets.load(Assets.java:12)
at com.saumi.game.Main.create(Main.java:25)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:149)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:126)
Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: File not found: KillSkull.png (Internal)
at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.read(FileHandle.java:136)
at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.readBytes(FileHandle.java:222)
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap.<init>(Pixmap.java:146)
... 8 more
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably just have to change the working directory. If you're working in Eclipse you can follow these steps:

1. Try to run your application once (it will fail).
2. Now go to **Run Configurations** by pressing the arrow next to the green **Run** button: [image: open_run_config]

   You should see a configuration called **DesktopLauncher** if step 1 was done correctly.
3. After pressing **Run Configurations...** you should be greeted with a popup window. From here you can change your working directory:

   1. Select **DesktopLauncher** from the dropdown on the left. The panel on the right should change.
   2. Select the **Arguments** tab from the panel on the right.
   3. At the bottom change **Working Directory** to **Other: Workspace**
   4. Find your project and select the `assets` folder.
      [image: Select working directory]

Answer (score -1):

Is the image located in another folder within the assets folder?
like assets/data/KillSkull.png if so you will have to 
include that folder name like this ->
killSkull = new Texture("data/KillSkull.png");

if the above one is not your case then try this out

killSkull = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("KillSkull.png"));

Answer (score -2):

After searching for this online the answer was actually something to do with run configurations.

You can find the answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/22833470

Comment: Please provide solution how you solved it and link to reference rather then just where you found an answer